# Create new files in a bash loop basing on a variable name

Tags: bash, file, directory

I'm new in the bash environment. I have a `for loop` that iterates along files in a folder. The loop instructions are to process these files and save them in a pre-existing folder (which is inside the working directory) renaming this saved file as the one in input. Here is the code:

```
for file in '$DIR'*.f* #take just the fasta files
    do command.py $file > $DIR/'translated'/$file
done
```

But the output is the following:

```
File or directory not existing
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Note that writing `'$DIR'` (in single quotes) won't work: single quotes mean that `$DIR` will not be expanded.

Comment: @larsks : Since this is the explanation for the error message the OP sees, I think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Hi @larsks, you are right but even removing the single quotes from my directory variable it is the same. It seems that the variable $file prints all the directory (e.g. /home..../file.fasta)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using relative paths.
Here the solution.

```
cd $DIR
mkdir ./new_folder
for file in *.f*
do 
    command.py $file > $file.modified
    mafft --auto *translated > $file.mafft
    mv *.modified ./new_folder
done
```